# Удалить один элемент, чтобы каждое число встречалось одинаковое количество раз

Tags: java, c++, c, алгоритм

Наткнулся на задачу.

Дан массив длины *n*. Необходимо найти максимальное число *l* (2 <= *l* <= *n*), чтобы для префикса массива *n* длины *l* выполнялось условие - **из него возможно удалить один элемент так, чтобы каждое число встречалось одинаковое число раз**

Пара примеров для наглядности сути задачи:

В примерах в первой строчке подается размер массива. В следующей строке через пробел перечисляются элементы.

**Пример 1**

Ввод:

5

1 2 3 4 5

Вывод:

5

**Пример 2**

Ввод:

10

1 2 4 2 3 1 3 9 15 23

Вывод:

7

Изначально была мысль, что как будто надо с мапой это связать, но так ни к чему и не пришел...

Буду благодарен любым идеям, как это сделать оптимальным способом!

Comment: Вам нужен алгоритм?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @Зонтик, мне нужна бы какая-нибудь идея для решения: алгоритм, структура данных или что-то иное, что могло бы помочь решить данную задачу наиболее оптимальным образом (примерно за секунду при длине массива 10^5)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вашу попытку решения. Хоть какую-нибудь. Правила запрещают решать задачи (даже интересные) за вас.

Comment: Казалось бы, просто мапа с ключами-числами, и значениями - количеством этих чисел. Чтобы на каждой итерации не проверять заново всю мапу, отдельно храните максимальное значение в мапе. Тогда умножив его на размер мапы и сравнив с количеством обработанных чисел, можно узнать, все ли там значения одинаковые.

Comment: Ваши примеры не совсем понятны - что значит 5 в примере №1, если длина массива равна 5 и все элементы встречаются по разу.  Почему во втором примере ответ 7?

Comment: И следует определиться с языком программирования.

Comment: @NowhereMan, согласен, возможно, действительно сложны для восприятия... Во втором примере  7 - это максимальный префикс, в котором можно удалить один элемент и оставшихся будет одинаковое количество. В первом же примере, если всех элементы встречаются по одному разу, то там тоже можно удалить один элемент и оставшихся будет одинаковое количество :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно трекать количество повторяюцихся значений и, например, если все значения повторяются 1 раз или, например, все значения повторяются Х раз и какое то другое только один раз, то сохраняем длину префикса.

Код может выглядеть как то так

```
int GetMaxPrefix(int[] data)
{
    var byNum = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    var byRepCount = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    var longest = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        var item = data[i];
        if (!byNum.ContainsKey(item)) byNum[item] = 1;
        else byNum[item]++;

        if (!byRepCount.ContainsKey(byNum[item])) byRepCount[byNum[item]] = 0;
        if (!byRepCount.ContainsKey(byNum[item] - 1)) byRepCount[byNum[item] - 1] = 0;

        byRepCount[byNum[item]]++;
        byRepCount[byNum[item] - 1]--;
        if (byRepCount[byNum[item] - 1] <= 0) byRepCount.Remove(byNum[item] - 1);

        if (byRepCount.Count <= 2)
        {
            if (byRepCount.Count == 1 && byRepCount.ContainsKey(1)) longest = i;
            if (byRepCount.Count == 2)
            {
                if (byRepCount.Values.Any(z => z == 1)) longest = i;
            }
        }

    }

    return longest + 1;
}
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine(GetMaxPrefix(new [] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}));
Console.WriteLine(GetMaxPrefix(new [] {1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 9, 15, 23}));
```

Вывод

```
5
7
```